# Has "when" been renamed in PromiseKit 3 for Swift2?

Tags: ios, swift2, promisekit

I am wondering why I can't get this example from the documentation of PromiseKit running: http://promisekit.org/when/

I have found out that .catch has been renamed to .error, and .finally has been renamed to .always, but what about "when"?

Or am I doing anything completely wrong? The documentation of PromiseKit is not very explanatory.

[image]

Comment: `when` works in PromiseKit 3. Are you sure you imported PromiseKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me. I had not imported PromiseKit in this file. I didn't notice because the .then{} syntax was working. The .then doesn't need PromiseKit to be imported.